# java.lang.String cannot be applied to LiveData<java.lang.String>. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android

Что нужно сделать чтобы исправить эту ошибку? Firebase требует java.lang.String, но в viewmodel используется LiveData.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<String> selected = new MutableLiveData<>();

  public void select(String item) {
      selected.setValue(item);
  }

  public LiveData<String> getSelected() {
      return selected;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полезно читать [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html)

У `LiveData` есть метод `getValue()` который возвращает значение.

Comment: а где его использовать?

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep в вашем коде это должно быть `model.getSelected().getValue()`

Comment: большое спасибо